# Idempotency of normalizing a binary number in coq

Tags: coq

I want to proof the idempotency of a function `normalize` that takes a binary number (as defined below, do note that `B0 (B1 Z) == 2`, so that they are  read right to left) and normalizes it by removing leading `0`s.

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | Z
  | B0 (n : bin)
  | B1 (n : bin).

Fixpoint normalize (m: bin) : bin :=
  match m with
  | Z => Z
  | B0 Z => Z
  | B0 m' =>
    match (normalize m') with
    | Z => Z
    | m'' => B0 m''
    end
  | B1 m' => B1 (normalize m')
  end.
```

```
Theorem normalize_idemp :
  forall b: bin, normalize b = normalize (normalize b).
Proof.
induction b as [| b' IHb' | c' IHc'].
- simpl. reflexivity.
- simpl. ???
Qed.
```

However I am stuck at the proof where I marked `???`. I tried destructing `b'`, but that does not help as I just get inside even m ore `match` patterns. How to complete the proof?

Comment: That is not the function that removes leading zeroes. Example normalize B0 B0 B1 B0 Z = B0 B0 B1 B0 Z. You can use Eval compute in to run your code and see the output.

Comment: @PedroAbreu welp that explains why I couldn't proof the theorem then. I'll try to write the correct normalize function now. I'll leave this question open if someone wants to do it and prove the theorem.

Comment: Once you fix the definition it's a trivial proof ;)

Comment: @PedroAbreu wait are you sure the definition is wrong? I tried with some examples, including the one you mentioned (`normalize B0 B0 B1 B0 Z`) and I got the expected output. (`B0 B0 B1 Z`).

Comment: Oh, the representation is supposed to be reversed? I didn't realize that, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructing `b` *does* work :

```
Theorem normalize_idemp :
  forall b: bin, normalize b = normalize (normalize b).
Proof.
  induction b ; cbn.
  - easy.
  - destruct b.
    + easy.
    + destruct (normalize (B0 b)).
      * easy.
      * cbn in *.
        now rewrite <- IHb.
      * cbn. now rewrite IHb.
    + cbn in *.
      now rewrite IHb.
  - now rewrite <- IHb.
Qed.
```

Note however that the fact that you single out the case of `B0 Z` makes the proof by induction unnecessarily involved. Instead you can simplify your definition to the following (try and prove both are equivalent if you want to convince yourself):

```
Fixpoint normalize' (m: bin) : bin :=
  match m with
  | Z => Z
  | B0 m' =>
    match (normalize' m') with
    | Z => Z
    | m'' => B0 m''
    end
  | B1 m' => B1 (normalize' m')
  end.
```

and the proof by induction is then even more straightforward.

Comment: Great, I didn't know the `cbn` tactic, `simpl` was reducing way too much, and I didn't realize I just needed to reduce half of it.

Comment: To quote the reference manual, *The cbn tactic was intended to be a more principled, faster and more predictable replacement for simpl.*

Comment: Both `simpl` and `cbn` are helpers that attempt to apply some heuristics in the unfolding of recursive functions.  These heuristics have a cost, and the *faster and more predictable* part of the claim is sometimes debated.  But `cbn` is often a good alternative to `simpl`.